# Shiny error message appears and dissappears immediately

Tags: r, shiny

Three selectInput options I have in my app. First is Class, second is Select Student and third is Exams. So when I chose class 1 in the 'Class selectInput', all the students name in class 1 is generated in 'Select Student selectInput'.

The error message pops for few seconds and then goes away while choosing the class choices in 'Class selectInput'. This also happens at the time of landing at the page.

Error message is **'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'**.

This doesn't happen if I remove the bar plot and render just the table output.

The app is online [here](https://loiyumba.shinyapps.io/pitambara/). You can see the error message yourself when you switch the Classes.

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/loiyumba/8375d89afa231094dddd39c5d56c9423).

Any hints gratefully received.